# Удалить конкретный документ, а не всю коллекцию Firestrore

Tags: swift, firebase, tableview

Есть table view, в котором отображается коллекция цветов пользователя. Когда пользователь переходит на detail VC, в котором может посмотреть информацию про выбранный цветок есть кнопка "Удалить", проблема в том, что я нашла только как удалить все цветы,

```
      db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("MyFlowers").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
          if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
          } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
              document.reference.delete()
            }
          }
        }
```

а нужно только выбранный.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("MyFlowers").document("your_need_id"){ err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error removing document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully removed!")
    }
}
```